# Intermediate steps to this simplifcation

Tags: calculus

Here's the problem

[image]

And immediately after is the solution, with no intermediate steps

[image]
What steps occurred in order to obtain the inequality after $Note$?

Comment: $|\sin(\frac1x)|\le1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known that for all $x$, $\sin (\frac{1}{x})^2 \le 1$

This implies that $-1\le \sin(\frac{1}{x}) \le 1$ was used.

In general,$-|t| \le  t\sin(\frac{1}{x}) \le |t|$.

In this case, $t=\sqrt [ 5 ]{x  } $

Comment: Why the square?

Comment: @EricJohnson To get that $\sin(\frac{1}{x}) \ge -1$.